# No se muestra la imagen de Splash al cargar App en el celular

Tags: java, android, xml

Tengo un código que saqué de un tutorial que supuestamente hace que se muestre la imagen de splash mientras se carga un WebView, y que cuando termina de cargarse, el splash se oculta:

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
       findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       findViewById(R.id.splashLoading1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Sin embargo, este no aparece nunca al probar la app en mi celular. El código completo del main_activity es éste:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.chapatelo.com.ar/");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                findViewById(R.id.splashLoading1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if(mWebView.canGoBack()){
            mWebView.goBack();
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    private class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{}
}
```

y el del activity_main.xml es el siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.chapatelo.www.chapatelo.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/splashLoading1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:src="@mipmap/splash"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"/>

<WebView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

En resumen, mis dudas son las siguientes:

1)¿Estoy colocanto el ImageView en la posición correcta (por encima del webview)?

2)¿Falta alguna función dentro del main_activity.java para que se muestre el splash y luego se oculte cuando la webview se terminó de cargar?

Nota: El Android Studio no me tira ningún error y compila la app correctamente tal y como la tengo, solo que la imagen de Splash nunca se muestra.

Comment: Este código no hace lo que dices. Necesitas usar AsyncTask

Answer (score 1):

Esto es incorrecto ya que al inicio de tu activity, carga una pagina y cuando termina de cargarse en el WebView estas haciendo visible el WebView e invisible el ImageView que contiene tu imagen de Splash y esto puede ocurrir en poco tiempo:

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) { 
   findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
findViewById(R.id.splashLoading1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: Se me muestra una pantalla en blanco y luego de unos 4 segundos mas o menos, se muestra la página cargada (el webview). Entonces, según lo que me decís, ¿cómo debería poner mi código para que se muestre la ImageView desde el momento 0 que abro la app, y que una vez que cargue el webview, esta imagen no se muestre más y el webview sea visible? Desde ya, muchas gracias!

Comment: Criss has una prueba comentando todo lo del webview y dime si puedes ver la imagen.

Comment: Puse el webview arriba del imageview porque al probar la app el splash no aparecia (ni tampoco en la pestaña "diseño" del android studio). Ahora que cambie de lugar ambos dos, el splash se ve en el android studio por sobre el webview. Sin embargo, aparece con unos márgenes izquierdo y derecho horribles y no se como sacarselos. Saque las medidas mdpi, hdpi, etc para hacer en photoshop las imagenes del splash para los diferentes tamaños de dispositivo. Pero sigue mostrándose con la altura total pero con márgenes a los costados. como puedo evitar esos márgenes y que el splash este fullscreen?

Comment: PD: Probé la app en mi celular y el Splash se muestra perfectamente bien ahora. Solo que me faltaría solucionar ese tema de los márgenes de la imagen en la pantalla ( o sea, que quede fullscreen)